Setting up firewall rules for ssh local port forwarding to access within LAN
I was trying to learn ssh tunneling. So
I set ssh local port forwarding to access web server running locally on the same machine as of ssh server:
ssh -g -L *:8080:localhost:80 user@10.8.0.1

GatewayPorts yes is set on server side.
My machine (ssh client) is at 192.168.56.0/24 with ip addr 192.168.56.102.
I guess with the given forwarding, any connection made to 192.168.56.102:8080 within LAN is forwarded and can access web page.
So, from another machine within LAN (192.168.56.101), I try to access the page from browser:
http://192.168.56.102:8080
But I was greeted with usual Hmmm… can't reach this page prompt.
I try to check if the machine is listenting. netstat -ano | findstr :8080 says:
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       812
TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       812

Turns out, it is. My guess, now moves to firewall. Maybe firewall is not allowing. Hence, I temporarily disable firewall and again try to access the page as such: http://192.168.56.102:8080. This time, I was given the page I want to access.
So, I thought, I should add some firewall rules to make this connection happen. Based on the traffic captured on the successful page access (to and from port 8080) as shown in image:
wireshark capture. Following rules were set to allow incomming and outgoing traffic to and from port 8080:
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow Incoming Port 8080" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow Outgoing Port 8080" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080

I checked the rules were added and firewall is on. Now again I go to access page but sadly again I was said Hmmm… can't reach this page.
I am not so good at writing firewall rules and just learning these ssh tunneling things. I am sure, I am mistaken somewhere understanding these. I will appriciate your help. BTW, ssh server is OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.5, OpenSSL 3.0.13 in linux host and client on Windows 10.
